# R - aggregate by group with some function

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to aggregate a data frame by a certain group and operation

**data**

```
> df <- data.frame(replicate(9, 1:4))
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
```

**aggregation**

```
> aggregate(df[,2], list(df[,1]), mean)
  Group.1 x
1       1 1
2       2 2
3       3 3
4       4 4
```

The above aggregation works, which is great. However instead of `mean`, in place of that I need to use combination of functions like `mean*sd/length^2`. Should we be using something other than aggregate here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your sample data frame in order to get a length and standard deviation for each group (you can't do this with only one data point per group).

```
> df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
3   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
4   4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
5   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
6   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
7   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
8   4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
9   1  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
10  2  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
11  3  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
12  4  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
13  1  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
14  2  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5
15  3  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
16  4  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
```

To aggregate by a more elaborated formula do:

```
aggregate(df[,2], list(df[,1]), function(x){mean(x)*sd(x)/length(x)^2})
  Group.1         x
1       1 0.2706329
2       2 0.3788861
3       3 0.4871393
4       4 0.5953925
```

If you want to have the same column labels you could do:

```
aggregate(list(X2 = df[,2]), list(X1 = df[,1]), function(x){mean(x)*sd(x)/length(x)^2})
  X1        X2
1  1 0.2706329
2  2 0.3788861
3  3 0.4871393
4  4 0.5953925
```

(or rename them afterwards with `colnames`)

Comment: You'll get prettier column names more easily if you use the formula interface: `aggregate(X2 ~ X1, df, function(x){mean(x) * sd(x) / length(x) ^ 2})`

Comment: You'll also get prettier names if you select lists instead of vectors by using `[` without a comma - `aggregate(df[2], df[1], function(x) mean(x)*sd(x)/length(x)^2 )` or `aggregate(df["X2"], df["X1"], function(x) mean(x)*sd(x)/length(x)^2 )` - the bonus being that this can then easily be scripted as the selection criteria are just text vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would do it with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(X1) %>% summarize(x = mean(X2)*sd(X2)/length(X2)^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(x = mean(X2)*sd(X2)/.N^2), by = X1]
```