# R -Finding Mean with multiple subsets

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a dataset with 4 columns as shown below. I want to create a 5th column (Mean) which has the mean of the 4th column based on the first 3 columns.

For e.g: The mean of the value in the first hour (hour=1) on the date (1/1/2018) for the Id (5000) is the mean of first 3 rows (2+2+1)/3 = 1.67

>

> head(read_df[,1:5])

`

```
 Id   Date         Hour         Value   Mean
5000    1/1/2018    1             1      1.67
5000    1/1/2018    1             2      1.67
5000    1/1/2018    1             2      1.67
5100    1/1/2018    4             2       2
5100    2/1/2018    6             2       3
5100    2/1/2018    6             4       3
5100    3/1/2018    2             7       7
5200    3/1/2018    3             3      4.5
5200    3/1/2018    3             6      4.5
```

I tried using a for loop for each of Id and Date and Hour. But ended up with NAs in some rows. Kindly let me know an efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325275/r-aggregate-by-group-with-some-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - aggregate by group with some function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325275/r-aggregate-by-group-with-some-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

read_df %>% 
    group_by(ID, Date) %>%          # Specifly your by-variables
    mutate(Mean = mean(Value)) %>%  # Calculate the mean
    ungroup()
```

Comment: Cool! This works. However does the "Mean" get "cbinded" to the read_df? could you tell me how I could do that?

Comment: @veggiecrunchburger `mutate` is a function to add new variable to a data.frame. You may refer to [http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) for details.

Comment: Went through the link shared and some more reads about dplyr. But I am facing this problem. I get the below message that Mean is available as the last column and [3 more variables: 'X <fctr>, Y <fctr>, Mean <dbl>']. But when I try to view the entire df (read_df), I am unable to see the Mean column. Any help or suggestions please?

Comment: @veggiecrunchburger It's because you haven't saved the Mean column in `read_df`. To do this, you can just add `read_df <- ` before `read_df %>% ...`

Comment: After several overcoming hiccups and other problems in my dataset, I finally finished this Hourly Mean with the exact code above. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

`ddply` from `plyr` does exactly this for *any* function.

```
plyr::ddply(read_df, c("Id", "Date", "Hour"), numcolwise(mean))
```

Though in your example I notice the 3rd row has a different date, so that contradicts your example.

There are simpler functions that can do similar things such as `aggregate`, but I like `ddply` as its a good all-rounder.

Comment: Sorry. That was a  typo. The objective is to calculate the hourly average based on the date and Id. I hope the above code works. I will try it out shortly.

Comment: In the second argument to `ddply` goes all the variables you want to group by. So if that is `Id`, `Date` and `Hour` keep those three in there. If it's just `Id` and `Date` take out `Hour` :)

Comment: It might also be worth editing your question so that the typo is fixed.

Comment: Edited the question as suggested :)

Comment: Can you please let me know why there is no "Value" as an argument in the "ddply" function you had provided above.